# Python3 program to swap elements

Tags: python, swap

```
def swapPositions(list, pos1, pos2):
    
    list[pos1], list[pos2] = list[pos2], list[pos1]
    return list

List = [23, 65, 19, 90]
pos1, pos2 = 1, 3

print(swapPositions(List, pos1-1, pos2-1))
```

i dont understand why "pos2-1" is used here why did they use minus one why doesn't it work without minus one??

Comment: It works without -1 , .e. `print(swapPositions(List, pos1, pos2))`. And don't use `list` as name/parameter.

Comment: indexes start at 0. Maybe the person who made this code wanted that `pos1 = 1` mean "the first element" and `pos2 = 3` mean "the third element". substracting 1 makes that possible, although it is very confusing with the selected variable names and without any coments

Comment: You could also do -2 or -7, it really depends on what the goal is and what the meaning of `pos` is.

Comment: btw. having a variable called `list` is a ***terrible*** idea.

Comment: @luk2302: having a type called `list` (with a lower case L) is an even worse idea, IMHO. But hey, it's Python. They can do strange stuff, as long as developers know what Python did wrong.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The reason why it takes "Pos2-1" is, the list index starts with 0(zero)

So

```
index    List
0         23
1         65
2         19
3         90
```

So if you don't give the "-1", then the function will take the index values of 1 and 3, which is 65 and 90.

If you find the explanation useful, accept it and vote for it